# How to simulate ionBlur in tests

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Maybe I'll start with what I want to achieve: I have a form with a required field. By default it should not display any error. The error should be displayed if a user touches the field. So my field looks more or less like this:

```
<ion-input .... (ionBlur)="updateDispayedErrors()"></ion-input>
```

But I don't know how to test it because:

1. Running `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.blur()` does not triggers `ionBlur` handler (the same with `....dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'))`)
2. Plain angular `(blur)` does not work (i.e. if I change the code to `(blur)="updateDisplayErrors()"` then it does not work)
3. It seems that calling `blur()` method on native `<input .../>` element that is created in the browser would work but... the problem is that when I run the tests `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.childNodes` is empty... So the native `<input .../>` is not created

Please let me know if you would like to see a full example to illustrate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a selector to `ion-input` like:

```html
<ion-input .... (ionBlur)="updateDisplayedErrors()" id="specialInput"></ion-input>
```

Then you can use `fixture.debugElement.triggerEventHandler`:

```ts
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

it('should emit ionBlur', () => {
    const ionDe = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#specialInput'));
    const ionBlurResult = spyOn(component, 'updateDisplayedErrors');
    ionDe.triggerEventHandler('ionBlur', {});
    expect(ionBlurResult).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```